# While plotting a array of shape (257, 55) I expect a spectrogram but I actually get a line graph. What is the error caused?

Tags: arrays, matplotlib, data-science, spectrogram

I have been using the VGGISH code and I need to plot spectrogram for different time stamps. I use matplotlib to plot the spectrogram but I do not get the correct results. 
My code

```
print(spec_slices[90].shape)
print(spec_slices[90])
plt.plot(spec_slices[90])
```

I know this is not the ideal way of asking a question. But I have uploaded images about what my array represents and the actual plot that I get.

[This image shows the shape of the array and also the values in the array.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJ2By.png)

[This is the result of plt.plot that I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyfOR.png)

Comment: `plt.imshow(spec_slices[90])`?

Comment: @QuangHoang thanks a lot for the help